# Eclipse saving file with different encoding although project is set up with a different one

Tags: eclipse, svn, utf-8

It's a web project I'm joining now and uses SVN for version controlling.
I went to eclipse properties and changed everything I found 'encoding' to UTF-8
Project's pom.xml has the `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>` property and default workspace encoding is also set to UTF-8. I have changed these settings before downloading the project(except for that on pom.xml) and I've also added `charset=UTF-8` on Preferences>Team>SVN>Properties Configuration>Automatic properties, to * File Name.

And yet windows saves my files with cp1252 encoding and browser can't show characters like á, é, ó, ê, etc

Comment: I am using Windows 7
On Windows 8, those steps or less were sufficient for solving the issue
Workaround I've been doing: Using my mac to program for the company.

Comment: What does 'Properties > Resource' show for the file encoding?